# Pagination in cassandra with Spring-data

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-jpa, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to get paginated results in cassandra using springboot, but I'm not getting desired results. Here is my code.

```
  Slice<User> usersByNameSlice =
      userRepository.findAll(CassandraPageRequest.first(10));
  while (usersByNameSlice .hasNext()) {
//.. process
    usersByNameSlice = userRepository.findAll(usersByNameSlice.nextPageable());
  }
```

I have around 35 users. This while loop works 3 times covering 30 users, but it comes out of the while loop after 30. How to solve this problem?

Comment: you can use the Paging and Sorting Repository if your only goal is the pagination

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to change the condition of the `while` loop to `usersByNameSlice.hasContent()` to check if there is content in the slice at all.

(Or maybe to combine it with check `isPaged()` even - because `nextPageable` on the last page will return unpaged state).